# Detecting knocks with minimum resources

Tags: signal-processing

I have this problem where i need to find 3 knocks (like on a door) , where i have a very limited resources (cant use big arrays) .
The advantage is that i don't care how they look, and only have to provide answer- yes or no , for a set of samples taken live ,

So , for every loop on the software i get a sample as integer . I then can wait for about second, to determine if there was something like this image :
[image]

Anything similar to this, would count as knocks.

The only option i see is to save previous data of huge arrays, but i am sure there is some clever way with just a few variables .

Comment: Couldn't you run a peak detection algorithm over your data and return yes if there's 3 peaks? Why would you need to save the previous data?